# Modify a JQuery select-style UL to work without BootstrapJS

Tags: jquery, html, css

My project uses JQuery 1.7.2 & JQuery-UI.

I would like to modify this select-style UL to work without Bootstrap.JS: [Select-style ul](http://jsfiddle.net/KSJEP/1/)

I've removed the Bootstrap dependencies & am experimenting here: [Modified select-style ul](http://jsfiddle.net/9WCSs/2/)

I've added the following JQuery to hide & show the ul menu, to mimic the function of the original, like so:

```
$(".select-list .dropdown-menu").hide();
$(".select-list").click(function () {
    $(".select-list .dropdown-menu").show();
})
```

How can I hide() the UL again when something is selected, or the user clicks outside the menu?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$(".select-list .dropdown-menu").hide();
$(".select-list").click(function () {
    $(".select-list .dropdown-menu").show();
});
$(".select-list .dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
.select-list .dropdown-menu {
z-index: 1000;
}
.mask {
position: fixed;
width: 30000px;
height: 30000px;
z-index: 999;
}
```

js:

```
$(".select-list .dropdown-menu").hide();
$(".select-list").click(function () {
    $(".select-list .dropdown-menu").show();
    $("div.mask").show();
})
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
    $(".select-list .dropdown-menu").hide();
    $(".mask").hide();
});
$(".mask").click(function(){
    $(".select-list .dropdown-menu").hide();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

html:

```
<div class="mask"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".select-list").click(function (event) {
    $(".select-list .dropdown-menu").toggle();    
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function(){
 if(!$(".select-list .dropdown-menu").is(':hidden'))
 {
        $(".select-list .dropdown-menu").hide();
 }  

});
```